# How to find a matrix declaration pattern in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm building a two-pass assembler in C.

A part of its job is to be able to work on matrices.

Let's say that there is the following line:

`mov m[r2][r5], XYZ`

`mov` is the operation.

and `m[r2][r5]` and `XYZ` are the operands.

I need to find out if an operand is a matrix. and get the:
1. matrix name.
2. row.
3. column.

How is it possible?

Tried to use sscanf without any success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [`regex.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regex.h.html) available on your platform?

Comment: What other patterns do you need to recognize?  Simple vectors?   Simple variables?  Can the vectors reference only appear on the LHS of the operands?  What did you try with `sscanf()`?

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately writing an assembler is not as easy as using the scanf. Simplifying: You need to divide the input stream into the tokens, then you need to parse it and build the semantic tree, then you need to do the semantic analysis, reduce the tree (by evaluating constant expressions, finding addresses etc etc), and eventually generate the machine code.

Comment: Hi Peter. first of all I'm using strtok to read the operands one by one.
The matrix validation needs to be implemented on a single operand only.
I ended up using the following pattern:
first of all, read the operand until it gets into '[' character. then: 
`res = sscanf(word, "[%[^]]][%[^]]]", row_register, col_register);` which simplified things for me.. Not sure it is the best way to do so though..